# Postgres Query Result of Rows with Different Column Value

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, distinct

I have rows of data in the same table that are differentiated by a column called kitdata which is a persons name. All other columns have various data.  But where the column called "resultid" (a number) has the same value in each of the persons kitdata name, I need to eliminate these rows from the output result.  So if Kevin & Terri have the same resultid number in their corresponding row, then the data is not shown in the results. The kitdata called kevin is the primary kit. I need to eliminate duplicate data in "terri" from my results.

Many variations. Including !=1

```
SELECT
  fulln, scm, kitname, sum (resultid)
FROM ftdnamc WHERE kitname !='terri'
GROUP BY
  fulln, scm, kitname
HAVING
  sum (resultid) != 0
```

Expected results would be data eliminated that has the same resultid as compared to the kevin and terri kitdata.

Answer (score 0):

`NOT EXISTS` will eliminate any rows when there is another row with the same value in the column `resultid`:

```
SELECT
  fulln, scm, kitname, resultid
FROM ftdnamc f
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM ftdnamc WHERE kitname <> f.kitname AND resultid = f.resultid
)
```

If you need to `SUM` the column resultid:

```
SELECT
  fulln, scm, kitname, SUM(resultid)
FROM ftdnamc f
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM ftdnamc WHERE kitname <> f.kitname AND resultid = f.resultid
)
GROUP BY fulln, scm, kitname
```